# Google recaptcha v3 recaptcha_response is null

Tags: recaptcha

i am using google recaptcha v3 in my website ,

here is the code i have added in my html web page in the head:

`<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=my public key"></script>`

```
<script>
               grecaptcha.ready(function () {
               grecaptcha.execute('my public key', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {
                   var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
                   ecaptchaResponse.value = token;
                       });
               });
</script>
```

and i added this in my form :

`<input type="hidden" name="recaptcha_response" id="recaptchaResponse">`

but when i submit the form and try to see the content of $_POST['recaptcha_response'] with var_dump()
it is just an empty string : string(0) ""

where is the mistake ?
thanks for answers !

Answer (score 0):

i tried lots of changes but everytime i get " token =  null " then i try this.. 100% working....

in Your Html

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="contact">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="hidden" name="captcha_token" id="recaptchaResponse" data-sitekey="YOUR-SITE-KEY">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg" id="submit-btn">
            SUBMIT
        </button>
    </div>
  </form>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=ReCaptchaCallbackV3&render=YOUR-SITE-KEY"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

after then add in your js file

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
        ReCaptchaCallbackV3();    
    }, 90000);
    
    $(document).on("submit",'#contact',function (e) {
      var token = $('[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val();
      console.log(token);
    });
});

var ReCaptchaCallbackV3 = function() {
    grecaptcha.ready(function () {
        grecaptcha.execute('YOUR-SITE-KEY', { action: 'contact' }).then(function (token) {});
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your original script you have a typo:

```
var recaptchaResponse = document.getElementById('recaptchaResponse');
ecaptchaResponse.value = token;
```

Instead of **recaptchaResponse**, you wrote **ecaptchaResponse**

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the problem by getting token like this:

```
var token = $('[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val();

grecaptcha.execute("{{config('site.invisible_captcha_site_key')}}", {action: 'submit'}).then(function(token) {
      var token = $('[name="g-recaptcha-response"]').val();
      if(token) {
        submit();
      }
    });
```